# Is a perfect insulator a reality

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, solid-state-physics

I recently came across [this article:](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/amp/wbna35605867)

> A perfect insulator, or a material that reflects heat while absorbing none of it, has been created by scientists at the Massachusetts Institute of Technology and Sandia National Laboratories. ...
>
> "All the heat that hits it gets shot back in the other direction," said Edwin Thomas, a scientist at MIT and co-author of a recent paper in the journal ACS Nano Letters describing the creation of a low-temperature perfect insulator. "If you could put the right material on the wall (of a home), the heat from your body would be enough to heat it."
>
> Now the MIT scientists have created structures 10 nanometers across that manipulate even tinier hypersonic waves gigahertz in size. Most people know hypersonic waves by a different name however: heat. When a sound wave becomes incredibly tiny, it actually functions as a heat wave.
>
> "Once you get into the regimen where you can affect a material's thermal properties this leads to other exciting possibilities," said Oskar Painter, a scientist at Caltech who wasn't involved with the MIT research. Sound could control heat. Light could control electricity. A whole realm of new devices could arise from this technology said Painter, but it will take years before they end up in consumer's hands

I know theoretically a perfect insulator would be possible but surely in practice this cannot be possible. If my understanding is correct all matter has a black body emission thus making it not possible??? And surely entropy would mean the degradation of the material so wouldn’t it have a “perfect insulator “ status for a limited time. My knowledge is limited but my interest is not

Comment: This link gives more detail into the theory and construction of this insulator. From my reading, the insulating properties of the crystal are frequency dependent so a blackbody comparison may not be correct: https://news.mit.edu/2010/perfect-insulator-0322

Comment: That does indeed elaborate more on the materials concept, and can grasp the principles behind a phonon exhibiting the same similar properties as a photon, having both characteristics of a particle and a wave, but (please forgive me if I’m wrong) wouldn’t the forces exerted at an atomic scale force it’s way through this loosing the contained energy like a surge in a crowd ?  And if it’s layered and of crystalline structure which is transparent allowing energy in the form of light in  but reflecting it back. would the material not still act like a heat sink for the other forms of energy??

Comment: I also understand the principle that at an atomic scale things like glass allow particles like light through without absorption of the energy due to the excitement of the electrons at the correct frequency, but as energy comes in many wavelengths and if certain layers absorb or reflect a particular wavelength would it not then radiate the contained heat. I’ll have to refresh myself on maxwell 

Comment: Im not an expert. The key feature is that they are manipulating the vibrations of the crystal (phonons) at gigahertz frequecies so this not optical radiation it's vibration of the lattice at infrared frequencies

Comment: Ahhh I must be mixing things up I thought infra red was only used to measure the vibration frequency by means of absorption and other wavelengths measured by X-rays etc